# Частичное изменение регистра в строке. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

появилась задача, где нужно частично изменить регистр в строке запроса.

У меня в запросе пользователь может сделать запрос в нижнем регистре, но далее идет проверка на верхний, а это я не предусмотрел и сейчас проблема как во время выполнения функции преобразовать запрос нижнего регистра в верхний. upper() не подходит, поскольку мне не нужна вся строка верхнего регистра. Использовал regexp_replace(), regexp_match(), но также не вышло.

Пример запроса пользователя:  `alter view "my_schema"."my_view" rename to "new_view"`

Хочу преобразовать в такое: `ALTER VIEW "my_schema"."my_view" RENAME TO "new_view"`

Также хотел бы учесть, чтобы можно было вместо rename to подставлять другие действий по ALTER как: set schema, owner to..
Есть у кого какие варианты для такого преобразования? Конечно можно везде replace() сделать, где нужно, но хотелось бы как-то красиво..

UPD: Запрос идет как строка (text)

Comment: Тот факт, что у вас пользователь может прислать SQL открытым текстом на сервер и сервер его сожрет - это уже само по себе дыра в безопасности размером с книжный шкаф из "Интерстеллара". На лиц*е*  [проблема X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710) и с ней надо разбираться в первую очередь.

Comment: @gbg Не все не так)) Я у себя в базе перехватываю свой же запрос и дальше применяю к нему действия. Это сейчас идет тестирование

Comment: Тогда опишите решаемую задачу более подробно. Сейчас непонятно, откуда и куда идет запросс и на каком этапе вы в него вмешиваетесь и какую цель преследуете.

Comment: @gbg Я пишу запрос на смену имени представления, но alter view и rename to у меня в нижем регистре. Я хочу преобразовать их в верхний регистр как `ALTER VIEW и RENAME TO`. При этом учесть, что вместо `RENAME TO` может быть также `SET SCHEMA` или `OWNER TO`. Смена регистра не должна никак затрагивать названия схемы и представления

Comment: Я могу сделать 3 строки по смене регистра используя replace() - это работает я уже проверил, но совершено не красиво

Comment: `но alter view и rename to у меня в нижем регистре` иииии как из этого вытекает проблема, что нужно менять регистр? Если что, postgresql абсолютно без разницы, напишете вы `ALTER`, `alter` или `AlTeR`

Comment: @Мелкий Да, postgresql на это все равно. Однако в моей функции есть условия, где я распарсивание строку на более мелкие (я выбираю из полученой строки схему и название представления, чтобы дальше с ними работать), но при этом должен учитывать, чтобы `alter view, rename to, owner to` были с больших букв

Comment: так вот тот свой парсер SQL и правьте, чтобы был регистронезависимый, как положено по стандарту.

Comment: @Мелкий Смотрите, в этом действии мне нужно, чтобы не только верхний регистр понимался, но был регистронезависимый `trim((regexp_match(_view__name,'^ALTER VIEW ["]?(.*?)["]?[\.]{1}["]?(.*?)["]?( ALTER| RENAME TO| SET SCHEMA| OWNER TO)(.*)$'))[1]);` Чтобы не только `ALTER VIEW` понималось, но и `alter view` или `ALTER view` 
`

Comment: так в чём сложность добавить модификатор i?

Comment: @Мелкий Благодарю Вас. Пропустил этот модификатор в документации...